# Unable to set the value of a SelectControl element

Tags: python, mechanize

I am trying to get machine-parsable bus schedule data by submitting a form with mechanize.

However, I am stymied by the mechanize syntax for setting

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("http://www.planibus.sto.ca/HastinfoWeb/StartTimetableForm.aspx")
br.select_form(name="TimetableQueryForm")
br["RouteDirectionDynamicComboBox$ComboBox_Input"] = "10 OTTAWA" # works fine, it's a TextControl
br["DatePicker$DaysDropDownList"] = ["3"] # This is a SelectControl
### mechanize._form.ItemNotFoundError: insufficient items with name '3'
```

`mechanize._form.ItemNotFoundError: insufficient items with name '3'` looks like it needs a list, but when I enter more than one item in the list (which makes little sense, given that this is a date picker) I get:

`mechanize._form.ItemCountError: single selection list, must set sequence of length 0 or 1`

I thought that my original `["3"]` was a sequence of length 1?

Thanks for your attention. I'm probably missing something obvious...

Edit: note that the '3' above is just one value, and the web site allows values for the next two weeks in its UI, so depending on when you see this, the list of allowable values will change. Just substitute the '3' with one of the allowable values... Still doesn't work for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 isn't one of the available select options, the options I see are

```
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
```

So try `br["DatePicker$DaysDropDownList"] = ["4"]` and your code should work.

Edit: I've actually tried looking at the page in question with mechanize, try this

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("http://www.planibus.sto.ca/HastinfoWeb/StartTimetableForm.aspx")
br.select_form(name="TimetableQueryForm")
select = br.form.controls[8] # DatePicker$DaysDropDownList
select.possible_items()
>>> []
```

There aren't any options, I imagine that javascript is used to populate them after the page has loaded. Unfortunatly [mechanize doesn't support javascript](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/faq.html#general), try using [Selenium Webdriver](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html) to scrape the data you need.

Comment: Yeah, the question was asked yesterday when "3" was a valid answer :-) I tried with (say) "10" and I get the same error

Comment: Selenium Webdriver is just too cool. I spent a few minutes with it and it looks like it will be a much better solution to my problem. And it was trivial to install with easy_install selenium. Thanks!

Comment: Great, glad to help. Look into pip, it's better than easy_install. `easy_install pip; pip install somepackage`